# No sound in headphones but speakers work fine

Tags: 14.04, sound, hdmi, headphones

I have an ASUS F550C Notebook running Ubuntu 14.04. I connected my PC to a screen via HDMI and the HDMI sound works fine and the computer's speakers work great as well, but when I plug in my headphones there's no sound whatsoever. What should I do to get sound from my headphones?

Comment: I know on raspi, there's also a headphone and hdmi jack. There is a config utility so you can choose where sound goes.

Comment: open terminal and execute
 "alsamixer" and check if headphones volume is fine there.

Comment: 4Wilhelm : I checked Sound Settings and chose the sound to go through headphones and still nothing.
4Don : Sound in alsamixer is good and it's not low or muted .

Comment: As Don already noted, open `alsamixer` in terminal, see if the column with headphones says MM at the botom

Comment: as I said everything is good in alsamixer